# Add columns to a reactive data frame in Shiny and update them

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I would like to be able to calculate a new column of data based on dividing one column by another, with both original columns selected by a user input. I would like to have this calculated data joined to the original table (or a copy of it).

I have managed to figure out how to make a dataframe that reacts to the column input selection, and I have managed to make a calculation that divides one column by the other, but I have not been able to make a final dataframe that includes all of the original columns as well as the new calculated one.

Here is a mock up I have made using the built in Iris data. It displays the data for the columns selected in the first table, and the calculation in the second table (you will need to scroll down quite far to see this).

How can I join this calculated data to the original source?

Many thanks

```
#Ui        
pageWithSidebar(
      headerPanel('Calculate Column'),
      sidebarPanel(

        #select variables from iris dataset
        selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', names(iris)),
        selectInput('ycol', 'Y Variable', names(iris),
                    selected=names(iris)[[2]])
      ),
      mainPanel(
        #display the selected variables
            tableOutput("view"),
         #display the calculated variable
            tableOutput("view2")
      )
    )


#Server
        function(input, output, session) {

      # Combine the selected input variables into a new data frame
      selectedData <- reactive({
        iris[, c(input$xcol, input$ycol),]
      })


      # divide one variable selection by the other
      selectedData2 <- reactive({
                iris$new<-iris[, c(input$xcol)]/iris[, c(input$ycol)]

        })

      # create data output for selected variables
      output$view <- renderTable({selectedData()
      })

      # create data output for calculated variable
      output$view2 <- renderTable({selectedData2()
      })

    }
```

Comment: I took the liberty of reformulating your title to better describe the actual question. There's no need to mention R and Shiny in the title, they're already in the tags.

Answer (score 12):

You forget that `iris` is NOT a reactive element, so your code can't work. You have two options here:

- creating a reactive value to store that data frame, using `reactive()`.
- creating a list of "global" reactive values in which you can store the updated data frame, using `reactiveValues()`.

### Using global reactive expressions with reactiveValues

Using `reactiveValues` you can make a list of reactive expressions much like `input` and `output` are. In the example below I use it to store the data frame `iris` as `globals$mydf`. Then you can use eg `observe` to change the value reactively, as in the following server function:

```
#Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  globals <- reactiveValues(
    mydf = iris
  )

  observe({
    thedf <- globals$mydf
    newvar <- thedf[[input$xcol]] / thedf[[input$ycol]]
    globals$mydf$ratio <- newvar
  })


  # create data output for selected variables
  output$view <- renderTable({
    globals$mydf
  })
}
```

#### using reactive()

You can make two reactive expressions that depend on eachother:

- one that selects the variables and calculates that ratio
- one that combines this result with the selected variables

Your server would look like this :

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  newdf <- reactive({
    cbind(
      iris[c(input$xcol, input$ycol)],
      Ratio = newvar()
    )
  })

  newvar <- reactive({
    iris[[input$xcol]] / iris[[input$ycol]]
  })

  # create data output for selected variables
  output$view <- renderTable({
    newdf()
  })

}
```

Although you beliefe this is not what you're looking for, you can use `newdf()` in other code just like you would use `globals$mydf` in the previous example. `reactiveValues()` especially pays off if different parts of your code have to be able to **change** the data frame.

Comment: that's great thanks for taking the time to solve and explain this

Comment: Both methods give me this error: Error in $: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: @Navid : A common cause for this error is to forget the brackets after the name or the reactive data (e.g. `newdf` instead of `newdf()` ).

Answer (score 1):

You don't return anything in your `reactive` for `selectedData2` you just do an incrementation `<-`, I think you should do this :

```
   function(input, output, session) {

  # Combine the selected input variables into a new data frame
  selectedData <- reactive({
    return(iris[, c(input$xcol, input$ycol),])
  })


  # divide one variable selection by the other
  selectedData2 <- reactive({
            new<-iris[, c(input$xcol)]/iris[, c(input$ycol)]
            return(new)

    })

  # create data output for selected variables
  output$view <- renderTable({selectedData()
  })

  # create data output for calculated variable
  output$view2 <- renderTable({selectedData2()
  })

}
```

Comment: thank you, I have tried using this code and it still seems to be behaving in the same way, is there anything else I need to change to end up with a dataset with all the original Iris variables and the new calculation?

Comment: @RobinNN You can use globals as shown in my updated answer