# Add new reactive column in Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I intend to add new column in a reactive way in R Shiny to be used for plotting. That is, after input changes by the user, the dataset is filtered again, and the new column is calculated again reactively.

Here is an example of a code I specifically prepared for you to test. So, in this code, what I want to show is a scatter plot of the count of each petal length as a function of petal length, and also color each point based on the custom category column I calculate and add to dataframe reactively.

I don't know which part I am making mistake at. I am getting error: "attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'"

Looking forward to your help.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

#Prepare dataset
iriss <- iris
iriss$Petal.Length <- lapply(iris$Petal.Length, function(x) round(x, 0))

all_species <- unique(iriss$Species)

ui <- fixedPage(
  titlePanel(h1(strong("Adding New Reactive Column - Test"), align = "center")),
      checkboxGroupInput("species", "Species", choices=all_species, selected=all_species),
      plotOutput("Petal_Count")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  #filter based on user input
  iris_selected <- reactive(subset(iris, Species %in% input$species))

  #groupby petal.length (count)
  iris_grouped <- reactive(as.data.frame(iris_selected() %>% count(Petal.Length)))
  
  #Add new category column reactively
  iris_grouped2 <- reactive({
    iris_grouped_new <- iris_grouped()
    iris_grouped_new$Categ <- reactive({
    ifelse(iris_grouped_new$Petal.Length >= 0 & iris_grouped_new$Petal.Length <= 1, '0-1',
    ifelse(iris_grouped_new$Petal.Length >= 1 & iris_grouped_new$Petal.Length <= 2, '1-2',
    ifelse(iris_grouped_new$Petal.Length >= 2 & iris_grouped_new$Petal.Length <= 3, '2-3',
    ifelse(iris_grouped_new$Petal.Length >= 3 & iris_grouped_new$Petal.Length <= 4, '4',
    ifelse(iris_grouped_new$Petal.Length >= 4, '4+', "")))))

       return(iris_grouped_new)
    })
  })
  
  #Plot scatter plot
  output$Petal_Count <- renderPlot(
    ggplot(iris_grouped2(), aes(x=Petal.Length, y=n)) +
      geom_point(size = 4, alpha = 0.8, aes(colour=Categ)) +
      geom_point(shape = 1, size = 4, colour = "black") +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(plot.background = element_rect(color = "black", size = 1), legend.position = c(0.85, 0.60)) + 
      labs(x="Petal Length", y = "Count") +
      guides(colour=guide_legend(title="Petal Length Group"))
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You’re *nesting* reactive expressions. That isn’t a good idea.

Comment: I'm not expert in shiny; I just found this idea in other posts :\ Looking forward to a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution, similar to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43278595/add-columns-to-a-reactive-data-frame-in-shiny-and-update-them).

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

iriss <- iris
iriss$Petal.Length <- lapply(iriss$Petal.Length, function(x) round(x, 0))

all_species <- unique(iriss$Species)

ui <- fixedPage(
  titlePanel(h1(strong("Adding New Reactive Column - Test"), align = "center")),
      checkboxGroupInput("species", "Species", choices=all_species, selected=all_species),
      plotOutput("Petal_Count")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  iris_selected <- reactive(subset(iriss, Species %in% input$species))
  iris_grouped <- reactive(as.data.frame(iris_selected() %>% count(Petal.Length)))
  
  newdf <- reactive({
    cbind(
      iris_grouped(),
      Categ = newvar()
    )
  })

  newvar <- reactive({
          ifelse(iris_grouped()$Petal.Length >= 0 & iris_grouped()$Petal.Length <= 1, '0-1',
          ifelse(iris_grouped()$Petal.Length >= 1 & iris_grouped()$Petal.Length <= 2, '1-2',
          ifelse(iris_grouped()$Petal.Length >= 2 & iris_grouped()$Petal.Length <= 3, '2-3',
          ifelse(iris_grouped()$Petal.Length >= 3 & iris_grouped()$Petal.Length <= 4, '3-4',
          ifelse(iris_grouped()$Petal.Length >= 4, '4+', "")))))
  })

  
  output$Petal_Count <- renderPlot(
    ggplot(newdf(), aes(x=as.numeric(Petal.Length), y=n)) +
      geom_point(size = 4, alpha = 0.8, aes(colour=Categ)) +
      geom_point(shape = 1, size = 4, colour = "black") +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(plot.background = element_rect(color = "black", size = 1), legend.position = c(0.85, 0.60)) + 
      labs(x="Petal Length", y = "Count") +
      guides(colour=guide_legend(title="Petal Length Group"))
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```